# Pointers and references to 'char buffer[128]'

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a simple program:

```
char buffer[128];                      // creates an array of 128 elements
memset(&buffer, 65, sizeof(buffer));   // fills buffer with 'A' (ascii 65) letter
cout << buffer << endl;                // prints whole buffer - 128 times 'A' letter
cout << &buffer << endl;               // prints adress of a buffer (first element of it)
cout << buffer[0] << endl;             // prints first element of a buffer
```

until now everything works great, but I can't understand why, when I call this:

```
cout << &buffer[0] << endl;
```

imho above code should print address of a first element in buffer (the same as `&buffer`), but it prints whole buffer, just like `cout << buffer << endl;`

why is that happens?

Comment: after the memset, add a buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1]= '\0'; because you will want a zero terminated string in some of those cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `&buffer[0]` is a `char*`, and there is an [`std::ostream& operator<<` overload for `const char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) which assumes it is the first element of a nul-terminated string, and prints its characters as such.

Answer (score 1):

```
&buffer[0] == buffer + 0 == buffer
```

and the whole array is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is the same. buffer[0] is de-referenciation of buffer with offset 0 (*(buffer+0)). Than you again calculate it's address and you get buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
cout << (void*) buffer << endl
```